# Design Database that Keeps Favorite Posts for Every User - Sugesstion Needed

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, database-design

> Offer:  offerID, title, thread ... 
>   Wanted: wantedID, title, thread ... 
>   Member: memberID, username ...

A member can pick many topics as favorite which will be put in a UI list. How can i design the db for it?

**My Solution:**

```
Favorite: 

favoriteID (PK)
memberID - FK
offerID - FK
wantedID - FK
```

**Many to many relationship. However, there always be NULL either in offerID or wantedID, is this ok?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're allowing multiple favorites per user, right?

Why don't you just use two tables then?

1) favoriteOffers

favoriteOfferID (PK)
memberID - FK
offerID - FK

2) favoriteWanted

favoriteWantedID (PK)
memberID - FK
wantedID - FK

You get the same functionality (maybe even more) with clear clean structure.

Comment: You are right...I was trying to avoid the given solution since i have few more than favorite and wanted. Most probably i will go with your sol.